# ComboBox Desabilitado

Tags: javascript

Buenas a todos, quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar con lo siguiente, actualmente tengo un combobox con una propiedad disabled

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de quitar ese circulo rojo que sale ahí, y remplazarlo mas bien con un pop up de la información del combo, muchas gracias

Adjunto código

```
{
  "mDataProp": "Fecha_Vencimiento", "sTitle": "Vencimiento", "orderable": true, "sWidth": "28%",
  render: function (data, type, row) {
    var stringOptions = "";
    $.each(row.TL_Lista_Fecha_Punto, function (key, value) {
      stringOptions += "<option data-inicio-type=" + lfConvertirFecha(value.TF_Fecha_Inicio) + " value='" + lfConvertirFecha(value.TF_Fecha_Punto) + "'>" + lfConvertirFecha(value.TF_Fecha_Punto) + "</option>";
      //stringOptions += "<option value='" + ConvertidorFechasMVC(ConvertirFechaFormato(new Date(ConvertirFechaJSON(value.TF_Fecha_Punto, "dd/mm/YYYY")), "dd/mm/YYYY")) + "'>" + ConvertidorFechasMVC(ConvertirFechaFormato(new Date(ConvertirFechaJSON(value.TF_Fecha_Punto, "dd/mm/YYYY")), "dd/mm/YYYY")) + "</option>";
    });
    return '<select id="lstPunto" class="combo"  data-none-results-text="No se encontraron coincidencias." disabled>' + stringOptions + '</select>';
  },
},
```

Comment: Se me ocurre adjuntarle un listener al combobox con el evento 'mouseover' y de ahí escribir la función que hará saltar el popup.

Comment: Podrías ayudarme con el código para hacer eso?

Comment: ¿El codigo esta completo? Te digo porque termina en una ,

Comment: Buenos días, compañeros es que en este caso lo que pretendo es que cuando yo pase el cursor del mouse por encima del combox bloqueado me salga el toltip en la información que contiene el combo en lugar del circulo rojo. Muchas gracias

Comment: @MauricioAcon: La el contenido de la pregunta debe incluirse en la pregunta misma, no en comentarios. Por otro lado el código no está completo. Favor de revisar [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

No deshabilites el select, sino no puedes manipularlo.
En el siguiente ejemplo, lo que hago es añadirle un `click()` al select y deshabilito las opciones que no quiero mostrar. En el momento que quieras vovler a usar ese select, lo único que tienes que hacer es retirarle la funcion y habilitar las opciones (y quitar la primera). Todo con jQuery.

```js
  $('#selectBox').click(function() {
    alert( "No puedes seleccionar ninguna de estas opciones." );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<select id="selectBox">
<option value="1">DESHABILITADO</option>
<option value="1" hidden>Option #1</option>
<option value="2" hidden>Option #2</option>

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El OP no ha preguntado por lo que respondes e incluyes tecnologias que el usuario no ha indicado como disponibles (JQuery). Ciñamonos a lo que se pide ;)

Comment: El OP esta usando (JQuery) en -> $.each, por lo que entiendo que es valido usarlo en mas sitios ¿no?. Ahora añado el pop up, eso se me ha pasado :)

Comment: No vi el $.each, en eso si tienes razon.

Comment: Buenos días, compañeros es que en este caso lo que pretendo es que cuando yo pase el cursor del mouse por encima del combox bloqueado me salga el toltip en la información que contiene el combo en lugar del circulo rojo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes ocultar el cursor de disabled con css

```
#selectBox:hover {
   cursor: default;
}
```

Como veo un foreach de jQuery facilmente puedes añadir un alert esmentando el disabled

```
  $('#selectBox').click(function() {
    alert( "Campo Bloqueado" );
  });
```

Sino con javascript seria

```
document.getElementById("selectBox").addEventListener("click", alert( "Campo Bloqueado" ));
```